# C# date range within date range restricted by threshold x

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've asked a similar question before but this is more in depth given that I figured out could of things since then. So believe me it's not repeated.

My user will use the system to make a reservation of room space and provide a start date and an end date by which his reservation should expire. Now there is a threshold of x number of seats in the room. Many bookings could be placed on the same date range as long as the rooms are available.

What am finding difficulty dealing with is the multiple reservation on the same date, and even worst when it comes to booking a date range within a booked range. That is having a booking from 10oct example until 20, then another booking starting from let's say 11th oct till 30 or 5th nov. how can I keep track of this reservation? It's been killing me for the past few weeks.

I am using SQL database to store reservation form data and c#  language of choice to develop asp application. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? Help with a data model to store a start and end dates? Help with logic to avoid over-booking? Help with UI?

Comment: I am asking help with c# code that would carry that comparison and tell me if I can book or not based on conditions I described

Answer (score 1):

Your bookings consist of two parts a start day and a duration. The booking exists for a set number of days for what I can tell.  One way to standardize would be to convert all booking to a list of Jullian days that they exits on.  This conversion is available in the [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) library and then you can utilize linqs set functions to see if a booking is overlapping.  I am sure there are corner cases but that is how I would approach the problem

Comment: Thanks rerun that's pretty good hints for reading the material. I will look into it and still would welcome others solutions